# Tomcat not starting due to JavaMail Message

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-mail

my Tomcat stopped working after I added some .jar files and tried some code. I am trying to send emails using JavaMail, so I copied some code online. I am quite newbie in some respects, so I don't really understand what is going on. What am I doing wrong?

After deleting the jars, replacing them, searching the web and feeling I was reverting to neanderthal I went back to the code I copied, commented it all and started uncommenting it line by line, and I found out that the exact part that is disrupting the Tomcat is "Message.RecipientType.TO". The weirdest part is that Eclipse won't show any error, everything seems to work fine until I try to start the server.

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.*;
import java.util.*;  
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class GrabarUsuario extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String to = "someEmail@gmail.com";
    String from = "someOtherEmail@hotmail.com";
    String host = "localhost";

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  

    try{  
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Ping");  
        message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  

        // Send message  
        Transport.send(message);  
        System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  

    }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}

}
}
```

**The error I get is this:**

(translation for the line in spanish:
No hay contexto de nombres asociado a este cargador de clase:
There is no context of names -or names context- associated to this class loader -or something like that-)

> ADVERTENCIA: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Victorial]]
>   so no cleanup was performed for that container
>   javax.naming.NamingException: No hay contexto de nombres asociado a
>   este cargador de clase    at
>   org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:985)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:968)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5704)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:593)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:829)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Comment: One thing to try is don't use the * in your import statements.  You may be getting a "Message" class you're not expecting as it's a pretty common name.  Any of the Java IDEs out there will help you create an import list with the explicit paths.  The com.sun paths are also quite old and probably not what you want.

Comment: I've already tried that, I just didn't copy everything because I didn't want to add too many things.

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with that line of code and I have no idea what's causing that error since your code above is not doing anything with JNDI naming contexts.  Perhaps some other part of your code is causing this problem?  In general your code above looks fine.  As long as the JavaMail jar file is in the right place, that code should at least execute.  Eventually you'll need to learn how to turn on [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) to solve your next JavaMail problem.

Comment: But if I comment that line everything else works fine. I'll check that JavaMail debug, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'll add in the maven dependencies I'm using on a working project which might help.  This packages with the application, and I don't make any changes to the default tomcat install:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.javamail</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I haven't updated this application in a while so there's probably newer versions of those available.

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, but you might want to try the [Oracle and now Eclipse version of JavaMail](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).